# Blazor Two Way Binding Text Area inside component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to two-way bind a text area inside a child component in Blazor and I just can't figure it out.

**Parent**

```
@page "/test"

<h3>Parent Component</h3>
<input type="text" @bind="mydata" />

<TWBTextArea @bind-ChildData=@mydata></TWBTextArea>

@code {
    public string mydata = "test";
}
```

**Child**

```
<h4>Child Component</h4>

<textarea @bind=@ChildData></textarea>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string ChildData { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ChildDataChanged { get; set; }
}
```

When I update from the parent component, the child textarea updates, but when I update the child text area, the parent is not updated.

Additional note : If I change the value being passed from a **string** to an **object with a string property** and I pass that object to the Child Component, two way binding DOES work but only after an update to the parent component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Important: You should not bind to components' parameters as it may have side-effects on your app. Read this post by [Steve Sanderson](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697588562)

Note that I define a local variable, named `data`, into which I assign the `ChildData` parameter property's value from the `OnParametersSet` method. That is done, as I've said before, in order to refrain from binding to a component's parameter.

Since we are creating a two-way data-binding, the value attribute of the textarea element is bound to the variable `data`. The flow of data is from the variable to the element. We also need to create an event handler, named here `HandleOnChange`, whose role is to update the local variable `data`, as well as to invoke the `EventCallback` 'delegate', passing the new value stored in the `data` variable. This value is gladly received in the parent component's `mydata` field, after which, a re-rendering occurs to reflect the new changes.

Note that I'm using the `input` event, instead of the `change` event, to make life easier and more interesting.

### Child component

```
<h4>Child Component</h4>

<textarea @oninput="HandleOnChange">@data</textarea>

@code {

    private string data;

    [Parameter] public string ChildData { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ChildDataChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleOnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        data = args.Value.ToString();

        await ChildDataChanged.InvokeAsync(data);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        data = ChildData;

        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
@page "/test"

<h3>Parent Component</h3>
<input type="text" @bind="mydata" @bind:event="oninput" />

<ChildComponent @bind-ChildData="mydata" />

@code {
    private string mydata = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The current version of Blazor seems to have what you need.
<InputTextArea @bind-Value="@prospect.Notes" Style="width:800px;height:200px;word-wrap:normal;" />
seems to work!

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputtextarea?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have it working now by inheriting InputBase and binding to the `CurrentValue` property, but it was definitely something of an uphill battle.

```
@inherits InputBase<string>


<textarea class="@Class" @bind="CurrentValue"
    @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" />


@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Class { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```